# How to display the confidence interval for only one of the regression lines within a mixed-effects model in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, mixed-models, confidence-interval

The following code creates a data frame with 3 columns.

```
set.seed(142222)
num_lots <- 5

# Create an empty data frame to store the simulated data
data <- data.frame(Lot = rep(1:num_lots, each = 9),
                   Time = rep(3 * 0:8, times = num_lots),
                   Measurement = numeric(num_lots * 9))

# Simulate purity data for each lot and time point
for (lot in 1:num_lots) {
  # Generate random intercept and slope for each lot
  intercept <- rnorm(1, mean = 95, sd = 2)
  slope <- runif(1, min = -.7, max = 0)
  
  for (month in 0:8) {
    # Simulate purity data with noise
    data[data$Lot == lot & data$Time == month * 3, "Purity"] <- intercept + slope * month * 3 + rnorm(1, mean = 0, sd = .35)
  }
}
```

And then I fit a mixed-effect model to the simulated data. As follow:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = Time, y = Purity, color = as.factor(Lot), shape = as.factor(Lot))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=FALSE, type = 1) +
  labs(
    title = "Test",
    x = "month",
    y = "Purity",
    color = "Lot",    # Set legend title for color
    shape = "Lot"     # Set legend title for shape
  ) +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24))
```

The result looks like the following:

[image]

**Question:** I want to show only the `95% lower confidence bound` on the `worst regression line`. How can I do that?

`Worst regression line` is the line which will intersect the horizontal line == 80 earlier than other lines.
I know if I set `se == TRUE` then all confidence bound for all of the lines will be shown. But I only want to have the lower confidence bound for only the worst line.

**Bonus question:** How can I fix the legend in such a way that only the symbols are shown (and not the line over them)?

Comment: For your bonus question try with `geom_smooth(..., show.legend = FALSE)`.

Comment: @stefan, thanks. Is there any parameter that only display upper or lower confidence bound (not the both bounds)?

Comment: Nop. I'm afraid this requires some kind of custom function using a `geom_ribbon` and perhaps `stat="smooth"` or computing the values for the confidence bands manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can plot two `geom_smooth()`s - one for the 4 'good' lines and one for the 1 'worst' line, e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(142222)
num_lots <- 5

# Create an empty data frame to store the simulated data
data <- data.frame(Lot = rep(1:num_lots, each = 9),
                   Time = rep(3 * 0:8, times = num_lots),
                   Measurement = numeric(num_lots * 9))

# Simulate purity data for each lot and time point
for (lot in 1:num_lots) {
  # Generate random intercept and slope for each lot
  intercept <- rnorm(1, mean = 95, sd = 2)
  slope <- runif(1, min = -.7, max = 0)
  
  for (month in 0:8) {
    # Simulate purity data with noise
    data[data$Lot == lot & data$Time == month * 3, "Purity"] <- intercept + slope * month * 3 + rnorm(1, mean = 0, sd = .35)
  }
}

ggplot(data = data,
       aes(x = Time, y = Purity, 
           color = as.factor(Lot), 
           shape = as.factor(Lot))) +
  geom_point(key_glyph = "point") +
  geom_smooth(data = data %>% filter(Lot == 2),
              method = "lm", se=TRUE, type = 1,
              key_glyph = "point") +
  geom_smooth(data = data %>% filter(Lot != 2),
              method = "lm", se=FALSE, type = 1,
              key_glyph = "point") +
  labs(
    title = "Test",
    x = "month",
    y = "Purity",
    color = "Lot",    # Set legend title for color
    shape = "Lot"     # Set legend title for shape
  ) +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24))
#> Warning in geom_smooth(data = data %>% filter(Lot == 2), method = "lm", :
#> Ignoring unknown parameters: `type`
#> Warning in geom_smooth(data = data %>% filter(Lot != 2), method = "lm", :
#> Ignoring unknown parameters: `type`
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula = 'y ~ x'
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula = 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

### Edit

Instead of using `key_glyph = "point"`, it's better to use `show_legend = FALSE` per @stefan's comment:

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(142222)
num_lots <- 5

# Create an empty data frame to store the simulated data
data <- data.frame(Lot = rep(1:num_lots, each = 9),
                   Time = rep(3 * 0:8, times = num_lots),
                   Measurement = numeric(num_lots * 9))

# Simulate purity data for each lot and time point
for (lot in 1:num_lots) {
  # Generate random intercept and slope for each lot
  intercept <- rnorm(1, mean = 95, sd = 2)
  slope <- runif(1, min = -.7, max = 0)
  
  for (month in 0:8) {
    # Simulate purity data with noise
    data[data$Lot == lot & data$Time == month * 3, "Purity"] <- intercept + slope * month * 3 + rnorm(1, mean = 0, sd = .35)
  }
}

ggplot(data = data,
       aes(x = Time, y = Purity, 
           color = as.factor(Lot), 
           shape = as.factor(Lot))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(data = data %>% filter(Lot == 2),
              method = "lm", formula = "y ~ x",
              se=TRUE,
              show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_smooth(data = data %>% filter(Lot != 2),
              method = "lm", formula = "y ~ x",
              se=FALSE,
              show.legend = FALSE) +
  labs(
    title = "Test",
    x = "month",
    y = "Purity",
    color = "Lot",    # Set legend title for color
    shape = "Lot"     # Set legend title for shape
  ) +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

### Edit 2

You can automate the selection of the 'worst' line in different ways; the easiest way is to select the Lot with the lowest Purity at Time = 0, but this may change depending on your data (i.e. maybe you want to select the Lot with the lowest Purity at Time = 24?). You can draw the upper bounds only, but you have to calculate the coordinates yourself, e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(142222)
num_lots <- 5

# Create an empty data frame to store the simulated data
data <- data.frame(Lot = rep(1:num_lots, each = 9),
                   Time = rep(3 * 0:8, times = num_lots),
                   Measurement = numeric(num_lots * 9))

# Simulate purity data for each lot and time point
for (lot in 1:num_lots) {
  # Generate random intercept and slope for each lot
  intercept <- rnorm(1, mean = 95, sd = 2)
  slope <- runif(1, min = -.7, max = 0)
  
  for (month in 0:8) {
    # Simulate purity data with noise
    data[data$Lot == lot & data$Time == month * 3, "Purity"] <- intercept + slope * month * 3 + rnorm(1, mean = 0, sd = .35)
  }
}

# Select the worst regression line
worst <- data %>% filter(Purity == min(Purity)) %>% pull(Lot)

# Build the 5 linear models
output <- data %>%
  nest_by(Lot) %>%
  reframe(model = list(lm(data = data, formula = Purity ~ Time)))

# Apply the models and extract the coordinates
preds <- predict(output$model[[worst]], newdata = data, se.fit = TRUE)
input_df <- data.frame(fit = preds$fit, se.fit = preds$se.fit) %>%
  bind_cols(data)
  
# Plot data and input_df
ggplot(data = data,
       aes(x = Time, y = Purity, 
           color = as.factor(Lot), 
           shape = as.factor(Lot))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = "y ~ x",
              se=FALSE,
              show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_ribbon(data = input_df, aes(x = Time, y = Purity,
                                   ymin = fit, ymax = fit + se.fit * 2),
              inherit.aes = FALSE, lty = 2, fill = "blue", alpha = 0.25) +
  labs(
    title = "Test",
    x = "month",
    y = "Purity",
    color = "Lot",    # Set legend title for color
    shape = "Lot"     # Set legend title for shape
  ) +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to automate the process of finding the worst line?

Comment: I also couldn't find any way to only display upper or lower confidence bound. Is it even possible to do that in geom_smooth?

Comment: In your example data the 'worst' line has the lowest value at time 0, so you could run `worst <- data %>% filter(Purity == min(Purity)) %>% pull(Lot)` before plotting, and change `geom_smooth(data = data %>% filter(Lot == 2),` to `geom_smooth(data = data %>% filter(Lot == worst),`. As for only plotting the upper bound, I'm not sure - I'll look into it

Comment: You can plot the upper or lower bounds if you calculate the coordinates yourself, but it's not 'simple'. I don't think there's an easier way sorry @JoetheSecond